# Base64 in CSS Files on SharePoint 2010 is Being Truncated

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css

First post, long time lurker. Hoping someone out there will have an answer to this oddity. I've searched Reddit, Stack Exchange, and Google without any luck.

I have a very strange issue with SharePoint...

My company is running a SharePoint 2010 Server with Enterprise Client Access License, On-Premises Farm, that no longer has a support contract, so no direct help from Microsoft. Also, the IT department doesn't have much experience with SharePoint.

We rely on the ability to upload HTML 5 content produced by various sites (Articulate, VisMe, etc.) and tools (Camtasia) for viewing by an audience that does not have Internet access (else, we'd just host the content online). These tools have Base64 encoded items found in the code that they output, specifically in .html and .css files. The encoded items have all been PNGs, SVGs, or fonts, and are in the src or url portion of an attribute.

Example:

```
.selector {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,datahere=');
    font-family: 'Lato Bold'; src:url('data:application/font-woff;base64,datahere=');
    background: url('data:image/png;base64,datahere');
}
```

The files will upload just fine, and work just fine for everyone. However, at what seems to be a random interval, the Base64 encoded content in the files is truncated. The amount of truncation is exactly the same each time it happens to a file. This first occurred with a few files about a year ago. After a few days of overwriting the files the issue stopped, so it was unfortunately assumed the issue was resolved.

Since the files are being stored in the SharePoint Database, we know the Windows 2008 server's antivirus isn't doing the truncating, and the SharePoint server's built-in antivirus is disabled. The issue occurs when the content is stored in a List or a Document Library. Two identical files can be in the same document library, in different folders, and only one copy will be affected.

The file version isn't changing and auditing logs show no changes to the files. Modified will be blank or show my name if I overwrote the file to fix it.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is occurring and hopefully a solution?

Thank you very much for any help!